# I wonder what this arrow stands for: $\mathbb R → \mathbb R$

Tags: functions, notation

[image]

I don't know if that stands for the result that $g(x)$ takes the value $x$
to the value $y$
But what I knew is $g(\mathbb R)= [-1,1]$ so its must be $\mathbb R → [-1,1]$ right ?

Comment: The arrow means that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$. The image of $g$, however, is only $[-1,1]$, so the function is not surjective.

Comment: That is a very standard notation.

Comment: Since $[-1,1]\subset\mathbb R$ the notation $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is as good as $\mathbb R\to[-1,1]\,.$ And that has not even anything to do with the question what the arrow stands for. Using $[-1,1]$ gives more information but is not mandatory.

Comment: @KurtG. And technically it's different. A function to $[-1,1]$ and to $\Bbb R$ cannot be the same, we just abuse one with the other

Comment: @FShrike I think this is a secondary question depending on the level of Bourbakism (mine is very low). My comment was more insisting against OP's view that for this function it *must* be $\mathbb R\to [-1,1]\,.$